# How to extend google maps from Dart

Tags: google-maps, dart

I'm using the google_maps package (v. 2.0.1). Now I'd like to use the MarkerWithLabel marker extension (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/).

My choices appear to be to create new Dart classes by cutting and pasting the Marker and MarkerOptions classes from the goggle_maps package or to somehow subclass of Marker (and MarkerOptions) in Dart.

The first option is just ugly, but I can't wrap my head around how to go about the second option. Am I missing something obvious? How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following wrappers should work :

```dart
class MarkerWithLabel extends Marker {
  MarkerWithLabel([MarkerWithLabelOptions opts])
      : this.fromJsObject(new js.JsObject(js.context['MarkerWithLabel'],
          [opts == null ? null : opts.$unsafe]));
  MarkerWithLabel.fromJsObject(js.JsObject proxy) : super.fromJsObject(proxy);
}

class MarkerWithLabelOptions extends MarkerOptions {
  MarkerWithLabelOptions();
  MarkerWithLabelOptions.fromJsObject(js.JsObject proxy)
      : super.fromJsObject(proxy);

  String get crossImage => $unsafe['crossImage'];
  set crossImage(String crossImage) => $unsafe['crossImage'] = crossImage;

  String get handCursor => $unsafe['handCursor'];
  set handCursor(String handCursor) => $unsafe['handCursor'] = handCursor;

  Point get labelAnchor => Point.$wrap($unsafe['labelAnchor']);
  set labelAnchor(Point labelAnchor) =>
      $unsafe['labelAnchor'] = labelAnchor == null ? null : labelAnchor.$unsafe;

  String get labelClass => $unsafe['labelClass'];
  set labelClass(String labelClass) => $unsafe['labelClass'] = labelClass;

  dynamic/*string|Node*/ get labelContent => $unsafe['labelContent'];
  set labelContent(dynamic/*string|Node*/ labelContent) =>
      $unsafe['labelContent'] = labelContent;

  bool get labelInBackground => $unsafe['labelInBackground'];
  set labelInBackground(bool labelInBackground) =>
      $unsafe['labelInBackground'] = labelInBackground;

  js.JsObject get labelStyle => $unsafe['labelStyle'];
  set labelStyle(js.JsObject labelStyle) => $unsafe['labelStyle'] = labelStyle;

  bool get labelVisible => $unsafe['labelVisible'];
  set labelVisible(bool labelVisible) => $unsafe['labelVisible'] = labelVisible;

  bool get optimized => $unsafe['optimized'];
  set optimized(bool optimized) => $unsafe['optimized'] = optimized;

  bool get raiseOnDrag => $unsafe['raiseOnDrag'];
  set raiseOnDrag(bool raiseOnDrag) => $unsafe['raiseOnDrag'] = raiseOnDrag;
}
```

Comment: Trying this gives the following error and stack trace:Uncaught Error: constructor not a function
    Stack Trace: 
    #0      JsObject._create (dart:js:119)
    #1      JsObject.JsObject (dart:js:117)
    #2      MarkerWithLabel.MarkerWithLabel      (package:canopy/marker_with_label.dart:8:31)

    Exception: constructor not a function
      undefined (undefined:0:0)

Comment: You should have forgotten `<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>` in your html.

Comment: I had a link to a local version in my html (right after the link to the google maps api if that matters). I substituted the link you provided: no change.

Comment: My mistake. I used `maps['MarkerWithLabel']` instead of `js.context['MarkerWithLabel']`. Answer fixed.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Display now works but mouse clicks get this error:Breaking on exception: type 'MouseEvent' is not a subtype of type 'JsObject' of 'jsObject'.

Comment: It turns out that the problem arises when you use a GSymbol for the icon. I have a little test app that demonstrates the problem if that would be helpful.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem by clicking on the label. Basically the code needs to override all the streams that handle `maps.MouseEvent` to handle `html.MouseEvent` too.